# Flexboxes overlapping in IE 11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm currently debugging a website to make it work on IE 11. Now there is one page, were there are two div tables inside a flexbox container. Under the container, there is another flexbox 'navLine', which should be positioned directly under the container. This works fine in every browser except IE 11. There the container and the navLine seem to overlap. Oddly enough, the navLine sticks to a button within the container. The button is within a cell of the div table, without any additional CSS properties.
Any help?

Here's the simplified code:

```css
#NavLine
{
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.SelectionBox
{
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  min-width: 570px;
  min-height: 410px;
}

.Container
{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#Box1, #Box2
{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 16px;
}

.Table
{
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
}
.Title
{
  display: table-header-group;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
.Row
{
  display: table-row;
}
.Cell
{
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">

  <!-- First Box -->
  <div id="Box1">
    <div class="Table SelectionBox">
      <div class="Title">
        <h2>Box One</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Item</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Value</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Item</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Value</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Item</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Value</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Item</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Value</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell"></div>
        <div class="Cell">
          <span> ([[result]]) Results</span>
          <span>Reset (this is a button)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Second Box -->
  <div id="Box2">
    <div class="Table SelectionBox">
      <div class="Title">
        <h2>Box Two</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Item</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Value</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Item</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Value</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Item</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Value</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Item</span>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
          <span>Some Value</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell"></div>
        <div class="Cell">
          <span> ([[result]]) Results</span>
          <span>Reset (this is a button)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="NavLine">
  <span>Back</span>
  <span>Next</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code.

Comment: @CarolMcKay done, but simplified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in IE is that `height: 100%` in `.Table.SelectionBox` is causing that element to overflow its container (`#Box1`). It then overlaps the `#NavLine` element, which is not causing any problem.

One way to fix the problem is to remove that height rule.

Comment: but then the two tables woudn't have the same height anymore, would they?

Answer (score 1):

"IE 11 requires a unit to be added to the third argument, the flex-basis property" - see "known issues" tab https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

also, a min-height might be required

so, try for example:

```
#container > div {
   flex:1 1 8em;
   min-height:8em;
}
```

Comment: Good you mentioned this, this could have resulted in other bugs. But it sadly didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Any SS may help better to understand the problem, could you please provide one?

Comment: @akashsingh I'm using polymer 2 and importing bower_components, I can not reproduce the result in a code snippet. I'll try to simplify and add it, may take a moment.